# Excel - Inserting Cell Values into Ranges

Tags: excel, range, cell, excel-indirect

I'm having problems inserting the value of a cell into a range. Right now I have:

```
=M3/SUM(M$3:M$13)
```

What I need is to be able to insert the value of another cell into that range, like:

```
=M3/SUM(M$A1:M$B1)
```

I have spent some time with the indirect function but I can't seem to get the syntax right. Does anyone know the correct syntax? Is indirect even the best/easiest/cleanest way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
=M3/SUM(INDIRECT("M" & $A$1 & ":M" & $B$1))
```

Not sure if you want A1 and B1 absoluted so I did it anyway.

Comment: Yeah I meant for the row reference (A1 and B1) :)